# requirements for Oracle HTTP Server

Tags: plsql-psp

For a personal project, I am trying to create a web page which displays some information from a database.

In order to have OHS, up and running, is it necessary to have already installed Oracle WebLogic Server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OHS will run independently from the WebLogic application server.

Answer (score 0):

For OHS 12c you have 2 options:

1) install Oracle HTTP Server collocated with an existing WebLogic Server domain

2) Standalone domain

More information and steps to install it can be found on the official doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/install-ohs/WTINS.pdf